# node.ReplaceChild()

Tags: asp.net

How do you use the node.ReplaceChild() method to replace `</td></tr><tr><td>` tag with the `<br />` tag when the `<tr>` tag only has 1 `<td>` tag?

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true; 
htmlDoc.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/myFolder/rpt.html").ToString());
if(htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null) 
{
   HtmlNode trNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//tr"); 
   if (trNode != null)
   {
      //check for more than 1 <td> in the same <tr> 
      bool td = trNode.ToString().StartsWith("</td><td"); 
      if (td == false)
      {
          trNode.ReplaceChild("</td></tr><tr><td>","<br />");
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that.  `</tr>` is the closing tag for a `<tr>` node, not a node in itself.  You'd need to process the two  nodes involved together.  Probably replace the first `<tr>` node with the combination that you're after, and then remove the second.